# How to add a jquery input slider or toggle switch

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to add a toggle switch to allow the data to update to either yes or no  on the table without actually clicking on the edit button. I am not sure how to go about this. I need it on the $e->Complete section. If it cant't be done in the admin_view then I will settle it in the edit_view page section but I need it so when they click on the yes or no that it automatically updates the post.

Admin_View.php page

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

<?php 
$msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg'); 
if ( (isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg)) ) { 
?>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" >
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <?php print_r($msg); ?>
    </div>
<?php 
} 

$msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg1'); 
if ( (isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg)) ) { 
?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" >
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <?php print_r($msg); ?>
    </div>
<?php 
} 
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table').dataTable();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#date').trigger('click');
    });

</script>

<div class="row-fluid" >
    <div class="span10"  style="margin-left:100px">          
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <i class="icon-truck"></i>
                <h3>Admin Callins Edit View</h3>
            </div>
        <div class="widget-content" align="center"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="table"> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="date" style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Date Scheduled</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Employee Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Employee Number</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Date Time Reported</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Reason</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Scheduled_Area</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Contact</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Approval Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Complete</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Edit</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center;  background-color:#4C9ED9; color: #fff;">Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
            <?php  $i=1; foreach($callin as $e ):?>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Date_Scheduled;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Employee_Name;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Employee_Number;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Time_Reported;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Reason;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Scheduled_Area;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Contact;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Approval;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $e->Complete;?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" >
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>callin/edit_callin/<?php echo $e->id?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#del_<?php echo $e->id?>" data-toggle="modal">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ;?>
     </table>

<!--Modal Start here-->

<?php foreach($callin as $d):?>  

<div class="modal fade" id="del_<?php echo $d->id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModal" aria-hidden="true" >   
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>callin/delete_callin" method="post" data-parsley-validate>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myAddLabel">Warning!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">                
                    <div class="box-body">
                         <div align="center" class="alert alert-error">
                            <h4>Are You Sure to Delete this Details</h4>
                         </div><br>
                    </div><br><br>
                    <div align="center"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $d->id;?>">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default"  data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

edit_view.php page

```
<DOCTYPE!>
<html>

<head>

<title>Edit Page</title>  

<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class"col-lg-6">
<div class="alert alert-warning">

<br><br>
<h4>Edit Call-IN</h4>


<?php $msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg'); if((isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg))) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" >

                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <?php print_r($msg); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $msg = $this->session->flashdata('msg1'); if((isset($msg)) && (!empty($msg))) { ?>
                <div class="alert alert-error" >

                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                <?php print_r($msg); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url();?>callin/update_callin" method="post">
<?php foreach($callin as  $e):?>


<div class="pull-left">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Date Scheduled:</label>
            <div class="btn btn-default" >
                <input type="text" class="default" name="Date_Scheduled" value="<?php echo $e->Date_Scheduled;?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-left">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Employee Name:</label>
            <div class="btn btn-default" >
                <input type="text" class="default" name="Employee_Name" value="<?php echo $e->Employee_Name;?>">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pull-left">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Employee Number:</label>
            <div class="btn btn-default" >
                <input type="text" class="default" name="Employee_Number" value="<?php echo $e->Employee_Number;?>">
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="pull-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"> Time Reported:</label>
        <div class="btn btn-default" >
        <input type="text" class="default" name="Time_Reported" value="<?php echo $e->Time_Reported;?>">
      </div>
    </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label"> Reason:</label>
    <?php
        $Reason = $e->Reason; 
        $options = array("Bereavement","Clinic","FMLA","ILL","ILL 2nd Day","Jury Duty",
          "ILL/PTO","IOW","Late","Late???","Layoff","Leave Early",
          "LeaveEarly FMLA","LeaveEarly ILL","LeaveEarly Personal","LeaveEarly FMLA","LNTB5H",
          "MIA","NCI","NCIBOD","NCIFL","NCOFL","Other","Personal","SAC","STO","VLO");
    ?>
    <div class="btn btn-default">
        <select name="Reason" class="default">
        <?php
            // Define $Reason here or the 'selected' attribute will not work
            foreach($options as $option){ 
                if($Reason == $option){
                    echo "<option value='".$option."' selected='selected'>".$option."</option>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php
        $Scheduled_Area = $e->Scheduled_Area; 
        $options = array("CLAIMS","TELECOM","CLEAN", "FLAT","HG SORT ",
          "HG TOTE","HANG 1","HANG 2", "INBOUND", "LP","MAINT","OUTBOUND",
          "PEP","QA/II","RACK SHOES", "REGIONAL DELIVERY","IT");
    ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Scheduled Area:</label>

    <div class="btn btn-default">
    <select name="Scheduled_Area"  class="default">
        <?php
            // Define $department here or the 'selected' attribute will not work
            foreach($options as $option){ 
                if($Scheduled_Area == $option){
                    echo "<option value='".$option."' selected='selected'>".$option."</option>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pull-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Contact:</label>
        <div class="btn btn-default" >
        <input type="text" class="default" name="Contact" value="<?php echo $e->Contact;?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Approval Name: </label>
        <div class="btn btn-default" >
        <input type="text" class="default" name="Approval" value="<?php echo $e->Approval;?>">
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Complete:</label>
    <?php
        $Complete = $e->Complete; 
        $options = array("NO","Yes");
    ?>
    <div class="btn btn-default">
        <select name="Complete" class="default">
        <?php
            // Define $Complete here or the 'selected' attribute will not work
            foreach($options as $option){ 
                if($Complete == $option){
                    echo "<option value='".$option."' selected='selected'>".$option."</option>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

    <br>

            <div class="footer" align="center">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $e->id;?>" name="id"> 
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default">
                <!--<input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default"> not working for some reason-->

                <button class= "btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>callin/list_callins'">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with sql server?

Comment: why not use a simple checkbox?

Comment: I figured slider would be easier for the user

Comment: So you need this feature to operate changes on database too, yes?

Answer (score 1):

I put this in the edit_view page

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="switch_options">
 <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Complete: </label>
    <span class="switch_enable"> Yes </span>
    <span class="switch_disable"> NO </span>
    <input type="hidden" class="default"value="<?php echo $e->Complete;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Complete" class="switch_val" value=""/>

</div>
```

In replace of this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Complete:</label>
    <?php
        $Complete = $e->Complete; 
        $options = array("NO","Yes");
    ?>
    <div class="btn btn-default">
        <select name="Complete" class="default">
        <?php
            // Define $Complete here or the 'selected' attribute will not work
            foreach($options as $option){ 
                if($Complete == $option){
                    echo "<option value='".$option."' selected='selected'>".$option."</option>";
                }
                else{
                    echo "<option value='".$option."'>".$option."</option>";
                }
            }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

    <br>
```

My jQuery code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.switch_options').each(function() {

        //This object
        var obj = jQuery(this);

        var enb = obj.children('.switch_enable'); //cache first element, this is equal to Yes
        var dsb = obj.children('.switch_disable'); //cache first element, this is equal to NO
        var input = obj.children('input'); //cache the element where we must set the value
        var input_val = obj.children('input').val(); //cache the element where we must set the value

        /* Check selected */
        if( 'NO' == input_val ){
            dsb.addClass('selected');
        }
        else if( 'Yes' == input_val ){
            enb.addClass('selected');
        }

        //Action on user's click(Yes)
        enb.on('click', function(){
            $(dsb).removeClass('selected'); //remove "selected" from other elements in this object class(NO)
            $(this).addClass('selected'); //add "selected" to the element which was just clicked in this object class(Yes) 
            $(input).val('Yes').change(); //Finally change the value to Yes
        });

        //Action on user's click(NO)
        dsb.on('click', function(){
            $(enb).removeClass('selected'); //remove "selected" from other elements in this object class(Yes)
            $(this).addClass('selected'); //add "selected" to the element which was just clicked in this object class(NO) 
            $(input).val('NO').change(); // //Finally change the value to NO
        });

    });

});


</script>
```

my CSS code is this:

```
<style type="text/css">

/* Main block */
.switch_options{
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica", Arial, Sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Main block clearfix */
.switch_options:before,
.switch_options:after{
    content:'.';
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}
.switch_options:after{clear:both;}

/*Options*/
.switch_options span{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 4px 9px;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #555;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
.switch_options span:first-of-type{
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    border-right: 0;
}
.switch_options span:last-of-type{
    border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
.switch_options span:hover{
    background: #fafafa;
}

/* Active option */
.switch_options span.selected{
    background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    border-color: #0082A3;
    color: #fff;
}


</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is on Admin_View.php, your table has some errors. you need to start the foreach loop before the `<tr>` tag. I would also try to place this inside `<tbody>` tags.

You have this:

```
<tr>
    <?php  $i=1; foreach($callin as $e ):?>
    <td>..</td>
    <!-- more tds -->
    <td>..</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ;?>
```

Change it to this:

```
<tbody>
<?php $i=1; foreach($callin as $e ):?>
    <tr>
        <td>..</td>
        <!-- more tds -->
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ;?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: the table is working but this is not the answer to the question. I figured out the answer and will post it once I am able to, but I will fix the error.

Comment: your table is messed up though, you need to fix that.

Comment: I did changed it to what you suggested

Comment: an error? you should have this: `<table><thead></thead><tbody></tbody></table>`

Comment: works fine just fixed it must of been something else

Comment: im also going to try move all my css out of there

Comment: I have probably a lot of code not needed on the page

Comment: I have the answer to this question on another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997396/how-to-make-a-switch-post-to-the-db-when-clicked