# How to make a switch button post to the db when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how to make a toggle switch button post to the db when it is pressed, so that it can update the info: **yes** or **no**. Like a submit button. This is in the view of my codeigniter app.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.switch_options').each(function() {

        //This object
        var obj = jQuery(this);

        var enb = obj.children('.switch_enable'); //cache first element, this is equal to ON
        var dsb = obj.children('.switch_disable'); //cache first element, this is equal to OFF
        var input = obj.children('input'); //cache the element where we must set the value
        var input_val = obj.children('input').val(); //cache the element where we must set the value

        /* Check selected */
        if( 'NO' == input_val ){
            dsb.addClass('selected');
        }
        else if( 'Yes' == input_val ){
            enb.addClass('selected');
        }

        //Action on user's click(ON)
        enb.on('click', function(){
            $(dsb).removeClass('selected'); //remove "selected" from other elements in this object class(OFF)
            $(this).addClass('selected'); //add "selected" to the element which was just clicked in this object class(ON) 
            $(input).val('Yes').change(); //Finally change the value to 1
        });

        //Action on user's click(OFF)
        dsb.on('click', function(){
            $(enb).removeClass('selected'); //remove "selected" from other elements in this object class(ON)
            $(this).addClass('selected'); //add "selected" to the element which was just clicked in this object class(OFF) 
            $(input).val('NO').change(); // //Finally change the value to 0
        });

    });

});


</script>
```

toggle switch html code

```
<div class="switch_options">
 <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Complete: </label>
    <span class="switch_enable"> Yes </span>
    <span class="switch_disable"> NO </span>
    <input type="hidden" class="default"value="<?php echo $e->Complete;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Complete" class="switch_val" value=""/>

</div>
```

controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Callin extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('callin_model');

        }   

    //Shows the dashboard
    public function index()
    {
         if($this->session->userdata('logged_admin'))
        {      
        $this->load->view('templates/admin_header');
        $this->load->view('insert_callins_view');


       }else{
           redirect('admin_authentication/admin_login_show');

        }

    }
    //Insert the callin 
    public function  insert_callin()
    { 
 if($this->session->userdata('logged_admin'))
        {     

    $data=array('Date_Scheduled'=>$this->input->post('Date_Scheduled'),
            'Employee_Name'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Name'),
            'Employee_Number'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Number'),
            'Time_Reported'=>$this->input->post('Time_Reported'),
            'Reason'=>$this->input->post('Reason'),
            'Scheduled_Area'=>$this->input->post('Scheduled_Area'),
            'Contact'=>$this->input->post('Contact'),
            'Approval'=>$this->input->post('Approval'),
            'Complete'=>$this->input->post('Complete'),
            'status'=>1);

        //print_r($data);

            $result=$this->callin_model->insert_callin($data); 
            if($result > 0) 
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Callin Record Added Successfully");
            redirect('callin');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"Callin Record Added Failed");
            redirect('callin');


        }

         }else{
           redirect('admin_authentication/admin_login_show');

        }

    }
    //List of callins 
        public function list_callins()
    {


         if($this->session->userdata('logged_admin'))
        {  


            $data['callin'] =$this->callin_model->get_callin();

            $this->load->view('templates/admin_header');
            $this->load->view('admin_callins_view',$data);

               }else{
           redirect('admin_authentication/admin_login_show');

        }


    }
    //List of callins
        public function viewlist_callins()
    {

           if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {  

            $data['callin']=$this->callin_model->get_callin();
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('user_callins_view',$data);


               }else{
           redirect('user_authentication/user_login_show');

        }
    }

    public function delete_callin()
    {
        $id=$this->input->post('id');
        $data=array('status'=>0);
        $result=$this->callin_model->delete_callin($id,$data);
        if($result==true)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"Deleted Successfully");
            redirect('callin/list_callins');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"callin Record Deletion Failed");
            redirect('callin/list_callins');


        }

    }



    public function edit_callin()
    {

        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['callin']=$this->callin_model->edit_callin($id);
        $this->load->view('templates/admin_header',$data);
        $this->load->view('edit_callin');


    }
    public function  update_callin()
    {


        $id=$this->input->post('id');

        $data=array('Date_Scheduled'=>$this->input->post('Date_Scheduled'),
            'Employee_Name'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Name'),
            'Employee_Number'=>$this->input->post('Employee_Number'),
            'Time_Reported'=>$this->input->post('Time_Reported'),
            'Reason'=>$this->input->post('Reason'),
            'Scheduled_Area'=>$this->input->post('Scheduled_Area'),
            'Contact'=>$this->input->post('Contact'),
            'Approval'=>$this->input->post('Approval'),
            'Complete'=>$this->input->post('Complete'));
            //print_r($data);   
        $result=$this->callin_model->update_callin($data,$id);
        if($result)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg',"Callin Record Updated Successfully");
            redirect('callin/list_callins');



        }
        else
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1',"No changes Made in Callin Record");
            redirect('callin/list_callins');


        }
    }

}
?>
```

model

```
<?php

class Callin_Model extends CI_Model 
{

    public function insert_callin($data)
    {
    $this->db->insert('callin_list',$data); 
return $this->db->insert_id(); 
    }
    public function get_callin()
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('callin_list');
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
        $this->db->order_by("Scheduled_Area", "desc");
        $this->db->order_by("Reason", "desc");

        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();


    } 
    public function delete_callin($id,$data)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('callin_list',$data);
            return print_r($data);


    }
    public function edit_callin($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('callin_list');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $query =$this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }
    public function update_callin($data,$id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->update('callin_list',$data);
        return print_r($data);

    }
}
```

Comment: what's a switch post?

Comment: sorry trying to clarify it. I was trying to figure how to post back a toggle that has either on or off in my case yes or no to the database without having to click on a submit button but on the toggle alone

Comment: There has to be an ajax code that can do this

Comment: ah. I get it now. You could either add something in the enb/dsb.click to ajax the value to a listener script that updates the value somewhere or if you actually want to submit a form, if there is a form tag you can just select that and do `$('#formID').submit()`.

Comment: it is not a form this is info showing in a table

Comment: So in the enb/dsb click handler do an ajax call that sends the value to a php script.

Comment: trying to figure how to do this not sure how

Comment: Replace the last line in your enb/dsb click handlers (`.change` call) with something like `$.get("scriptThatSavesValue.php?newValue=Yes");`. Change the script name or create one that saves the value.

Comment: I don't know how I would go about writing a script in ajax to save the value I will keep trying to look online to see what I can come up with

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<div class="switch_options" for='<?php echo $Employee_Number;?>'>
 <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Complete: </label>
    <span val='true' class="switch switch_enable"> Yes </span>
    <span val='false' class="switch switch_disable"> NO </span>
</div>
<script>
$('.switch').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('for');
  var complete = $(this).attr('val');
  var that = this;
   $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>edit_complete",
        type: "post",
        data: 'complete='+complete+'id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            if (data.indexOf("Edit complete OK") >= 0){
              $(that).addClass('selected');
              $(that).siblings('.switch').removeClass('selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

You will need a controller to work your database query.Here it is:

```
 public function  edit_complete() { 
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_admin')){ 
      $complete_value = $this->input->post('complete');
      $Employee_Number = $this->input->post('id');
      if($this->callin_model->edit_complete($Employee_Number, $complete_value)){
        echo 'Edit complete OK';
      }
   }
 }
```

And inside your model:

```
function edit_complete($Employee_Number,$complete_value){
  $data = array('Complete' => $complete_value);
  $this->db->where('Employee_Number', $Employee_Number);
  $this->db->update('mytable_name', $data);
  if($this->db->affected_rows()==1)return TRUE;
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to just make the toggle stick with the change doesn't have to post maybe that would be easier

Comment: Well, that depends on what you need to obtain by that. If you want the change to be seen by other users, you need to post it and retain it in your database.

Comment: I can help with your controller too if you give me your database table column names.

Comment: I have a controller want me to post it above

Comment: I posted the current controller

Comment: This is weird it is only showing first ten records for my toggle switch and not the rest so the first ten is blue rest is not

Comment: I'll go ahead and design some new function for your controller, then I'll update my answear. Then we deal with other esues.

Comment: Ok thank you I may not get to it till tomorrow got to go to work.

Comment: it is getting triggered but now I have error 500 server error need to see why that is happening

Comment: It is probably the db query. Echo `$this->db->last_query();` in your model before the **if** declaration, see if that is ok, eventualy test it in phpmyadmin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72876/discussion-between-veronica-and-valentin-valentin).